# Restful Webservices Post Request with Curl Command in Dropwizard

Tags: java, web-services, rest, curl, dropwizard

I'm facing problems with POST requests from both `curl` and the browser.

```
package name.christianson.mike.resource;

import com.google.common.base.Optional;


import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import name.christianson.mike.model.Time;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

@Path("/time")
//@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TimeResource {


    @GET
    public Time getTime(@QueryParam("timezone") Optional<String> timezone) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        //TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone.or(defaultTimezone));
        //formatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        String formatted = formatter.format(new Date());
        return new Time(formatted);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getTrackInJSON() {
        System.out.println("fdfsf");
        //Track track = new Track();
        //track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        //track.setSinger("Metallica");

        return "HI";

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public String createTrackInJSON(@FormParam("param1") String param1 ) {

        //String result = "Track saved : " + track;
        System.out.println(param1);
        return param1+"fdf";

    }
}
```

In dropwizard my jar is running... I need to request post request..i tried with browser form submission and also it didn't work..

So I tried curl, but it also didn't work.

```
curl -X POST -d "param1=dds" http://localhost:9179/time/post
```

My yml file

```
defaultTimezone: UTC

server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 9179
      outputBufferSize: 32KiB
      idleTimeout: 30 seconds
      minBufferPoolSize: 64 bytes
      bufferPoolIncrement: 1KiB
      maxBufferPoolSize: 64KiB
      acceptorThreads: 1
      selectorThreads: 2
      acceptQueueSize: 1024
      reuseAddress: true
      soLingerTime: 600s
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 9180
```

Comment: I see just a GET call. Don't see a resource for POST.

Comment: What you mean by "didn't work"? What was the error that was returned?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't specify content type in your command

Try to call this command:

```
curl -X POST -d 'param1=dds' -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://localhost:9179/time/post
```